# Textarea в новой строке добавлять <br>

Tags: php, jquery

Пользовтаель вводит тест в textarea:

```
Здравствуйте,
Чем то могу вам помочь?.
```

Когда сохраняем в базу чтобы текст был:

```
Здравствуйте,<br>
Чем то могу вам помочь?.
```

Или же вместо `<br>` можно `\n`

При выводе теста из textarea выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем в базе нужно \n? Что с этими двумя символами потом делать?

Comment: Это даст вывести текст в виде первая строка:`Здравствуйте,`
Вторая строка:`Чем то могу вам помочь?.`

Comment: Не понял вопрос, что нужно сделать??

Comment: С какой стати косая палочка и латинская буква n будут чему-то помогать? Откуда такая информация? Где это написано?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT Есть textarea  - width:100px когда пишет пользователь и доходит до 100px унего спускается в новую строку и дальще пишет.Я сохраняю textarea в базу а там всё в одну строку.

Comment: Тебя жестоко обманули.

Comment: "После этих слов и подтвердилась драка." - Судари, становится понятно, что в действительности проблема у человека в том, чтобы выяснить, где текст в `textarea` заворачивается на новую строку. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Видимо проблема в том, что в textarea не было перевода строки, т.к. текст был перенесен из-за нехватки места и отключенного скроллбара.  Может стоит добавить в textarea скролы?

Comment: @IVsevolod перевод строки всегда есть. Просто некоторые его не видят

Comment: @Ипатьев судя по этому "Есть textarea - width:100px когда пишет пользователь и доходит до 100px унего спускается в новую строку и дальще пишет" - здесь пользователь не ставит перевода строки хотя на экране отображается как перенесенный.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, добавлять `<br>` надо не при записи в БД, а при выводе в браузер.
Во-вторых, для этого в РНР есть функция nl2br()

Comment: nl2br() она \r\n меняет на <br> и что это изменит??.

Comment: @Sauron http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 3):

Укажите атрибут `wrap="hard"` для элемента `textarea`. Тогда в полученном на сервере тексте между завернутыми строками будут символы перехода на новую строку, которые Вы сможете преобразовать в `<br />` во время вывода html.

```
<textarea name="comment" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp

Answer (score -1):

Надо делать так:

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text
And one more line</div>
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?